# GoRouter - Web - How to detect that the user entered an URL in the browser's address bar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-routes

I'm using [`go_router`](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) on web and I would like to implement a different `redirect` logic between the call of the `go_router`'s API (`push`, `go`, `replace`) and when the user enters an URL in the browser address bar.

I didn't find any solution and I was going to implement it this way:

If I understood correctly, when the user enters an URL in the browser address bar, it restarts the application from scratch, while calling the API doesn't. And I came to this:

```dart
bool _isFirstRedirect = true;

GoRouter(
  routes: myRoutes,
  redirect: (state) {
    if (_isFirstRedirect) {
      // Logic when the user enters an URL in the browser's address bar.
      _isFirstRedirect = false;
    } else {
      // Logic when it comes from a call of the go_router's API.
    }
  }, 
);
```

But I'm not sure that is a good design. Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [initialLocation](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/go_router/GoRouter/GoRouter.html) in `GoRouter` constructor. Something like this:

```
GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/page3',
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (context, state) => const Page1Screen(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/page2',
      builder: (context, state) => const Page2Screen(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/page3',
      builder: (context, state) => const Page3Screen(),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: `initialLocation` is used when you start the application on mobile, right? Setting it doesn't make sense in my context since I'm talking about the url given by the user in the address bar of the browser

Comment: It doesn't matter if it Android, iOS, web or something else, it is used set an initial location for routing.

Comment: I don't think you understood what I'm trying to do. As a user using the web app, I can enter any URL in the browser's address bar (It can be `/page1` or `/page2/subpage2` or anything else). I want to detect that when the user goes to `/page1` (for example) to have a different behavior between coming from the `GoRouter.push` or a user that types the URL  in the address bar.